# How to avoid Ds_Store and pods while pulling in Xcode source control?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, version-control

My team member pushed pods and ds_store. We use .gitignore file and also added everything to ignore. But still getting conflicts on every pod files and all when I pull it in my mac.

How can I remove them all and make it future friendly without any errors anymore.

This is how my conflict looks:
[image: my conflict]

Comment: do `git rm -rf Pods` to remove it from the repo and then it wont be tracked.

Comment: but what about ds_ Store

Comment: do the same, and make sure that it is in the .gitignore file

Comment: doesnt help..showing the same

Comment: should i remove it from remote?

Comment: i am a beginner in git..can u explain what should i do first in terminal

Comment: if you have both files in the .gitignore and do `git rm filename` (`git rm -rf folder`) that removes it from the repo and shouldn't be tracked. you need to commit this change for it to take affect.

Comment: thank you..can u write it as example of one file

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the files are already tracked by git.

So you need to remove them from the repo.

To remove a single file...

```
git rm README.md
```

To remove a folder...

```
git rm -rf Pods
```

Once you have done this you will need to commit the change to the repo and then those files/folders should no longer be tracked as long as you have them listed in the `.gitignore` file.

```
git add . 

git commit -am 'refactor: remove un needed files' 

git push
```

To recursively remove all DS_Store folders from the repo do

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

Comment: but when i go through git..there is Ds_store file in every folder

Comment: I added to my answer

Comment: Auto-merging Nahda School/Podfile.lock
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Nahda School/Podfile.lock
Auto-merging Nahda School/Podfile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Nahda School/Podfile
CONFLICT (modify/delete): Nahda School/Nahda School/.DS_Store deleted in HEAD and modified in abd87c1ee2ba72b8c42dc988d43c8d2b8dc635d3. Version abd87c1ee2ba72b8c42dc988d43c8d2b8dc635d3 of Nahda School/Nahda School/.DS_Store left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): Nahda School/.DS_Store deleted in HEAD and modified in abd87c1e

Comment: somewhat like this

Comment: just delete them again, its because you are merging branches... one has deleted them all and one hasn't. but you do want them deleted so just delete again, commit and push

Comment: what should i do next?

Comment: i am stuck in no where

Comment: `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete && rm -rf Pods`

Comment: problem fixed..but it shows pull (that download icon ) on most files even after pulling

Answer (score 0):

First remove,

```
rm .DS_Store
```

then pull,

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Last login: Fri Mar 20 21:58:42 on ttys000
imac@iMACs-iMac ~ % cd /Users/imac/Desktop/nahda-national-school 
imac@iMACs-iMac nahda-national-school % rm .DS_Store
rm: .DS_Store: No such file or directory
imac@iMACs-iMac nahda-national-school %

Comment: git pull origin master
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
imac@iMACs-iMac nahda-national-school %

Comment: i am confued..OMG

Comment: Then you might have conflicts, resolve those before merging.

Comment: You want to remove all conflicting files?

Comment: there are more than 100 files